Formatting with exam package, parskip, and minipage
I'd like to use parskip, exam package, and minipage together.
Parskip provides really nice spacing to my eye, in conjunction with exam package.
However, to get questions not to split across pages, I would like to use minipage package. The problem is that the spacing gets all weird. In my example below, either the font size or between word spacing is different, as well as list spacing.
Ideally between 1 and 2 (non mini-page and mini-page), I could get 2 looking exactly like 1. However the exam package and parskip provide complication and I don't know how best to go about this.
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{parskip}

% Wrapper command to put each question in a minipage
\newcommand{\questionp}[1]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \question #1
  \end{minipage}}


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

  \question Test question where we have a very long explanation so we can see how the spacing differs between examples.
  
  \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice Test 1 where when we also have a couple lines it is easier to see
    \CorrectChoice Test 2 where when we also have a couple lines it is easier to see
    \choice Test 3
  \end{checkboxes}

  \questionp{
    Test question where we have a very long explanation so we can see how the spacing differs between examples.
    
  \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice Test 1 where when we also have a couple lines it is easier to see
    \CorrectChoice Test 2
    \choice Test 3
  \end{checkboxes}
  }

  \end{questions}


\end{document}


The minipages  have paragraph skip of 0pt by default, no matter what is is set elsewhere. Add \the\parskip to both  questions and compare.

@Fran  Awesome. I see outside of minipage it was "6.0pt plus 2.0pt" and inside minipage was "0.0", so now setting parskip inside minipage I think I have fixed it, I'll write an answer

Putting a \question inside a minipage seems dangerous.  Try \newcommand{\questionp}[1]{\question \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}

@JohnKormylo  I will give this a try. It looks good at first blush, except spacing between questions is weird (too narrow) even after adding setting parskip

Taking the advice of a commenter. After checking spacing with \the\parskip, I added a spacing command to the minipage and it appears to have solved my issue and now formatting matches.
% Wrapper command to put each question in a minipage
\newcommand{\questionp}[1]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6.0pt plus 2.0pt}
  \question #1
  \end{minipage}}

